# Conditional function for excluding first image from content, not working

Tags: functions, images, the-content, conditional-content

I have the following function:

```
function remove_images( $content ) {
    if( ( is_category() || is_archive() || is_home() ) && has_term( 'MyCat', 'category', $postID ) ) {
        $postOutput = preg_replace("/\< *[img][^\>]*[.]*\>/i","",$content,1);
    return $postOutput;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_images', 100 );
```

What it is meant to do is remove the first image in the_content() on thew index page (all listing pages) only for those posts in the MyCat category. What it is doing, instead, is removing the first image from the_content() on all posts for the index page, and removing the_content() altogether on **all** of the **single pages**. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is this code in full? Where does `$postID` come from?

Comment: `$postID = get_the_ID();` I defined it above the function. Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: Yep, you need to define variables inside function (or declare them as global), in current form it will always be `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What it is doing, instead, is removing the first image from the_content() on all posts for the index page...

That's because that's what your callback is telling the filter to do. It returns true for *all posts* in your specified contexts (archive index, category index, blog posts index), *not* just for the *first post* in those indices.

> ...and removing the_content() altogether on all of the single pages.

That's because, if your conditional returns false, you don't return anything. You need to `return $content;` outside of your conditional.